# How to create a template EZPL code

Tags: c#, printing, zpl

I've developed a client server printing system using GoLabel app to print labels using Godex printers. In this system, a print job request is sent from client to server and server generates a PRN code using GoLabel. And the prn code is sent to the client again.

The system mostly works but in a case when clients send multiple requests simultaneously, the server opens up multiple instance of Golabel and this causes the CPU spikes.

To solve this issue, I would like to prepare an EZPL template and insert parameters into this EZPL string.

I use this method with ZPL codes. Here is a ZPL code example:

```
^XA
^BY2,3,100^FT30,156^BCN,,Y,N,,A
^FD==Parameter0==^FS
^FO20,15^A0N,25,20^FB350,4,0,C
^FD==Parameter1==^FS
^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ
```

In C# code, I retrieve information from a database and insert them into this string in the place of Parameter0 and Parameter1.

When I check a EZPL code generated by GoLabel, I don't understand how godex printers get these parameters. Example:

```
^Q152,3
^W101
^H5
^P1
^S3
^AD
^C1
^R0
~Q+0
^O0
^D0
^E16
~R255
^XSET,ROTATION,0
^L
Dy2-me-dd
Th:m:s
Y2242,86,Image12-14
Y1900,105,WindowTextBox10-24
Y2060,2662,WindowTextBox8-49
Y782,88,WindowText6-36
Y330,2540,WindowText5-48
Y216,2541,WindowText4-33
Y94,2531,RichTextImage3-48
Y89,2652,WindowText2-88
Y1262,97,WindowTextBox1-88
Y581,2478,Image0-96
Lo,2209,92,2220,3490
Lo,1930,2461,2188,2472
BH,758,36,9,22,582,1,1,12345678901
E
```

Is there any way to insert parameters as a string programmatically (in C#) ? If this is not possible, how can I assign text values into the parameters generated by Golabel (for instance in this line, "Y89,2652,WindowText2-88", assigning my raw data into WindowText2-88 field). Most importantly, how can I put my image into this EZPL template ?